# If $\lim (s_n) = s$ is an element of $S$ then $S$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm doing a homework assignment, working on the following question:

> A set $S$ is closed iff whenever $(s_n)$ is a convergent sequence of points in $S$, the limit of $(s_n)$ is also in $S$.

I've finished the proof for $S$ is closed $\implies \lim(s_n) = s\in S$, but am having some trouble with $\lim(s_n) = s \implies S$ is closed.

Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: How have you defined "closed"?

Comment: Note that the result is not true in topological spaces in general; both from the statement of the theorem and the real-analysis tag I assume that you’re working in a metric space.

Comment: Our definition is S is closed iff S contains all its accumulation points, or that S = S union bdS

Comment: @BrianM.Scott The assignment specifically says to prove the theorem so I would assume that it's not false for the space. The assignment also doesn't state that S is a subset of R

Comment: The fact remains that the theorem is not true in general; it requires some extra assumption on the ambient space. If you’re working with general metric spaces, the assumption is most likely that $S$ is a subset of some metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$. If you’ve only been working in the Euclidean spaces $\Bbb R^n$, then the assumption is most likely that $S\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: @Brian If S is subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and you are in a metric space then this part is obvious because in metric space the limit of sequence is unique.(In arbitrary topological space limit is not unique as Brian M.Scott ) said.

Comment: We've been working almost exclusively in R.

Comment: Okay; then you should probably assume that $S\subseteq\Bbb R$. For the direction that’s giving you trouble, try showing that if $s$ is in the closure of $S$, then there is a sequence in $S$ that converges to $s$.

Comment: How is this?

Suppose lim(sn)=s is in S. Let (sn) be a convergent sequence of points in S and let s be an accumulation point. Since (sn) tends to s, we have an N such that for all n >= N , |sn - s| < epsilon  for all epsilon > 0, and hence s is in N*(s; epsilon) for all sufficiently large n. Since all points in (sn) are in S, N*(s; epsilon) intersect S is not empty for all epsilon > 0. Therefore S' is a subset of S and S is closed.

I don't yet know how to use LaTeX commands, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction: suppose $\;S\;$ is not closed, then there exists an accumulation point  $\;x\;$ of $\;S\;$ s.t. $\;x\notin S\;$ , but this means that in any neighbourhood of $\;x\;$ there is a point $\;s\in S\;$ .

Now, going into $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ as proposed to you in the comments, the above means that for any

$$n\in\Bbb N\;\exists\,s_n\in S\;\;s.t.\;\;|x-s_n|<\frac1n$$

Now build a sequence $\;\{s_n\}\subset S\;$ s.t. $\;s_n\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{}x\;$ and get your contradiction.

Hint on the construction: let $\;s_1\in S\;$ be s.t. $\;|s_1-x|<1\;$ . Now let $\;r_2:=\min\{1/2\,,\,|s_1-x|\}\;$ and using that $\;U_2:=S\cap \mathcal O(r_2,x)\neq\emptyset\;$ (why? Take into account that $\;\mathcal O(r_2.x)\;$ is the *open* ball with radius $\;r_2\;$ and centered at $\;x\;$ ) chosee any element in the intersection to be the second element of the sequence $\;s_2\in U_2\;$ , and etc.